# Make a valid request to Dingo API with guzzle (laravel 5.1)

Tags: laravel, api, curl, guzzle, dingo-api

I create an API and when I test API with POSTMAN everything is fine but when I try to make a request:

```
$client2 = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['verify' => false ]);

$res3 = $client3->get('https://app.EXAMPLE.com/api/update/'.$serial, [
    'headers' => [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$token,
    ],
    'form_params' => [

        'token' => $token,
        'bookingdate' => '07/07/2018 12:00 am',
        'notes' => $SpecialRequests
        ]
]);
```

to my API I got:

[image]

> RequestException in CurlFactory.php line 187: cURL error 18: transfer
>   closed with outstanding read data remaining (see
>   http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

What is the problem here? in Postman works fine but request from my app won't work

Answer (score 1):

You are using GET with `form_params`. It's wrong by design (you cannot send any data with GET, only with POST/PUT).

So I'm pretty sure that this is the reason. Change to POST or remote the the data from the request.

Comment: I try with POST but I got error: data
:
debug
:
{line: 113, file: "/home/perica/public_html/vendor/dingo/api/src/Auth/Auth.php", class: "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\UnauthorizedHttpException", trace: Array(47)}
message
:
"Failed to authenticate because of bad credentials or an invalid authorization header."
status_code
:
401

Comment: Sorry, I have no clue about your backend server, what authentication it wants. The internal error is from there.